# How add text in Rectangle in Javafx

Tags: javafx, rectangles

How do I add a text at the center of a rectangle? I've been searching and have not found a way to do this.

See the class below:

```
public class Agent extends Rectangle{         

    public Agent() {
        setWidth(60);
        setHeight(60);
        setArcWidth(60);
        setArcHeight(60);                
        setFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET.deriveColor(0, 1.2, 1, 0.6));
        setStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
     }    
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add the `Text` element and the `Agent` (`Rectangle`) element in a `StackPane`.

```
Text text = new Text("...");
...
StackPane stack = new StackPane();
stack.getChildren().addAll(agent, text);
```

Comment: Worked, but in the following manner:
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Text text = new Text("...");
        stackPane.getChildren().add(agent);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(text);
        paneContent.getChildren().add(stackPane);

"stack.getChildren().add(agent, text);" // Incompatible types, because add(int, node)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `addAll(agent, text);`

Comment: Ok, I used addAll(agent, text);

Comment: I used the following to forward mouse events on the `Label` to the `Rectangle`: `label.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, e -> rect.fireEvent(e));`

Comment: I don't want to use `StackPane` because it stacks all child nodes on top of each other in z-order. Is there any other way to make it work without using `StackPane`?